Could not get unknown property 'usesUnsupportedDependencyVersions' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project
Steps to reproduce
melos clean && melos bootstrap
fvm flutter pub get
fvm flutter pub upgrade
fvm flutter pub run build_runner clean
fvm flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
running project
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file '/Users/herisarwanto/AndroidStudioProjects/FREELANCE/99Group/NEW-Rumah123-Pro/rumah123-pro-apps/packages/app/android/app/build.gradle' line: 4

What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin']



Failed to apply plugin 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin'.
Could not get unknown property 'usesUnsupportedDependencyVersions' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Error: Gradle task assembleDevDebug failed with exit code 1

This issue has been resolved in my monorepo project by following these steps:

Delete Gradle cache
In the android directory, clean the project:
./gradlew clean
In the /app directory, delete the .dart_tool folder, then run:


fvm flutter pub get
fvm flutter pub upgrade
fvm flutter pub run build_runner clean
fvm flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs


In the root project directory, run:
melos clean && melos bootstrap

